# Spectre/Meltdown Windows vs. Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, security, cpu-architecture

I use a Notebook with an AMD E2-1800 processor which did not get any microcode updates.

That means it is not quite protected against Spectre/Meltdown. In Ubuntu there is a very well explained wiki for this kind of problem. But unfortunately no information can be found for Windows 8.1 which I am currently using.

My question is, what is protected and what not for an AMD processor without microcode updates but with all the Windows updates installed?

Which system would be easyer to attack via Spectre/Meltdown: Ubuntu 18.04 or windows 8.1?

Comment: Why do you need protection against Spectre/Meltdown? For this attack to be used your computer needs to be already infected, so what's the point?

Answer (score -1):

https://www.techarp.com/guides/complete-meltdown-spectre-cpu-list/2/ shows your AMD E2-1800 processor is not listed as vulnerable to either Meltdown or Spectre.

The outdated Windows 8.1 will always be easier to successfully attack than an up to date OS such as Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, per [Computerworld](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3252823/why-linux-is-better-than-windows-or-macos-for-security.html), IDC's [Techworld](https://www.techworld.com/picture-gallery/developers/linux-vs-windows-10-3670807/), [Lifewire](https://www.lifewire.com/windows-vs-linux-mint-2200609), [MakeUseOf](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-things-ubuntu-better-windows/), the [UK's GCHQ](https://www.zdnet.com/article/uks-security-branch-says-ubuntu-most-secure-end-user-os/), and numerous other sources.

Comment: It would be wonderful if you quoted the relevant information from your link.